# How to test whether a prediction interval truly captures 95%?

Tags: binomial-distribution, validation, prediction-interval

I want to analyze the 95% prediction intervals for a model. The true values should fall within the prediction intervals 95% of the time (on average) if the interval is well calibrated. If the proportion of times that the true value falls within the prediction interval departs widely from 95%, in either direction, then the method for constructing prediction intervals likely needs to be changed. I have searched for literature on the topic of validating prediction intervals, but I have struggled to find anything. Here is my proposed method for validating prediction intervals:

If I know the true values, for $n$ prediction intervals I end up with $n$ Bernoulli trials, where a "success" is defined as the true value falls within the prediction interval. I then conduct a Binomial test to analyze whether the true probability of success is 0.95

Is this a reasonable way to validate a model's prediction intervals? Is there literature on this topic that I am missing?

Comment: Are these classical or Bayesian prediction intervals?

Comment: They're bootstrapped prediction intervals (Bollen-stine). But I would think that you should be able to analyze prediction intervals agnostic to the methodology, so that you can compare different methods for calculating them.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that simple, which is why I had to ask.  The two definitions are substantially different.  The classical definition of prediction intervals concerns the joint probability distribution of the original sample and future observations, whereas the Bayesian definition concerns only the posterior distribution developed from a prior distribution and the data.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why that would affect what I am talking about here. If I gave you predictions and purported 95% prediction intervals, but didn't tell you how I calculated them, why couldn't you just analyze how often the prediction interval captured the true value?

Comment: I think your idea is reasonable, at least for the classical definition of prediction intervals. For the last step, I prefer CI (confidence interval), instead of a Binomial test.

Comment: It's an issue because the very *meanings* of those intervals are different.  It may be confusing that they go by the same name.